# Render table cells (td) with different HTML tags in React

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, code-reuse

I am developing a React application that fetches data from an API and renders it into a Table. I have 3 components: `Row`, `Body` and `Table`. `Table` fetches the data, passes it to `Body`, `Body` passes it to `Row`, which then renders the cells.

The problem I am facing is that data in a `Row` is both text and images. This is how my`Row` component looks:

```
const Row = props => {
  return(
    props.data.map(row =>
      <tr key={row.id}>
          {props.cols.map(col =>
             <td>{row[col.name]}</td>
          )}
      </tr>
   )
  );
}
```

The data fetched from the API takes the form:

```
data = [
  {
    "firstName": "Jack",
    "lastName": "Sparrow",
    "id": "jckspr"
  }
]
```

However, I am also required to render a small image static in the fourth column by `<img src="images/logo.png">`. But I am unable to render this image with the current code logic I have implemented i.e. I cannot render this in `Body`:
`<Row data={data} cols={tableHeaders}>`, with `tableHeaders` being

```
[
  { header: "First Name", name: "firstName" },
  { header: "Last Name", name: "lastName" },
  { header: "id", name: "id" },
  { header: "Image", name: "image" }
]
```

How can I achieve the functionality I want while maintaining a resusable and extensible code architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new component for cells

```
const Cell = ({ colName, value }) => {
  if (colName === 'image') {
    return <img src="images/logo.png" />;
  }
  // Other if's for other possible cell types
  // ...
  // Otherwise return the value
  return value;
}
```

Then update the **Row** component:

```
const Row = props => {
  return(
    props.data.map(row =>
      <tr key={row.id}>
          {props.cols.map(col =>
             <td>
               <Cell colName={col.name} value={row[col.name]} />
             </td>
          )}
      </tr>
   )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a good idea. However, I am facing an issue with this. The data I receive from the API takes the form of the `data` array I specified in my question, so it doesn't have the `Image` field. Using `row[col.name]` wouldn't work unless I add an `Image` field to every object using `map`. This is inefficient because the array is huge with many objects. Do you know how else I could achieve this?

Comment: You could rely on col.name to define the way you render the cell. I'll update the answer with this idea.